# How do I convert each element of a string array to an integer? (VB)

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net, integer

For my current task I have to read in an 8 digit card number using an array. I have declared my array as this at the beginning of my code:

```
Dim LoyaltyCardDigits(8) As Integer
```

The reason I declared this as an integer is because I need to carry out calculations on these array elements after it has been read in.
I am reading in 8 characters from a textbox and then assigning these characters to a variable.

```
CardNumber = txtCardNumber.Text
```

and I am assigning these characters to the array elements; but this is my problem that I am stuck on.

```
Private Sub btnSubmitDetails_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmitDetails.Click

    For Counter = 1 To 8
        LoyaltyCardDigits(Counter) = Mid(CardNumber, Counter, 1)
    Next Counter
```

So to conclude I would like a solution to convert the array elements from string to integer so I can perform calculations. I have no need to worry about validation as I have already coded it. As I am extremely new to VB I would prefer if any help was as simplified as possible but I will obviously accept anything that works.

Comment: The first thing to note is that .NET arrays are zero-based, so the indexes in your array should go from 0 to 7. The second thing is that you have told us what you want to do and provided the code you've used to do it, but not explained how the behaviour of that code doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: Here is the error message I receive upon clicking my Submit button-      An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You said you already took care of validation, so try something like:

```
Private Sub btnSubmitDetails_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmitDetails.Click
    If CardNumber.Length = 8 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To 7
            LoyaltyCardDigits(i) = CInt(CardNumber.Substring(i, 1))
        Next

        ' ... now do something with LoyaltyCardDigits ...

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this and I am receiving this message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Controlled Assessment Project.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Which line is it pointing to?...gonna need more information to help you.

Comment: I edited it and it seems to be working fine now, thank you.